# How to make eldoc only popup on demand?

Tags: eldoc, posframe

I installed the [`eglot`](https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot) package to use for C++ development, and it's going fairly well, but one thing that's driving me nuts is the [`eldoc`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElDoc) package. I have a 13 inch MacBook and it's constantly inflating the minibuffer to about 20% of my screen height to tell be about stuff I don't care about. I don't want to uninstall it, because I like the idea of seeing documentation, *when I want to*. Is there a way to stop it from showing anything as you move the cursor around, and instead use a specific command to trigger the doc display?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. I can't find a way to turn off the eldoc hover support and setting the idle timer to something really large means that the on-demand commands are never populated with information.

Answer (score 3):

To get this

***`eldoc-help-at-point` (bound to `C-h D`)***

[image: eldoc-help-at-point]

***`eldoc-box-hover-mode`***

[image: eldoc-box-hover-mode]

1. Install [`eldoc-box`: Display ElDoc documentations in a childframe.](https://github.com/casouri/eldoc-box)
2. Copy the following snippet to `my-eldoc-theme.el` under `custom-theme-directory`.

```lisp
(deftheme my-eldoc "Created 2022-10-08")

(require 'eldoc)
(require 'eldoc-box)

(custom-theme-set-variables 'my-eldoc
                            '(global-eldoc-mode t))

(custom-theme-set-faces 'my-eldoc
                        '(eldoc-box-body
                          ((t
                            (:background "yellow")))))

;; (add-hook 'eldoc-mode-hook
;;        'eldoc-box-hover-at-point-mode)

(add-hook 'eldoc-mode-hook
          'eldoc-box-hover-mode)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-h D") #'eldoc-box-help-at-point)

(provide-theme 'my-eldoc)
```

2. `M-x load-theme RET my-eldoc RET`
3. Try hovering over a symbol, what happens
4. Try `C-h D` on a symbol, see what happens

Comment: This answers the "popup" part of the question, but this is still happening on hover... it's not "on demand".

Answer (score 0):

I've also wanted this, and was helped by the author of eglot to reach a solution in
https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot/discussions/1328

The main trick is to let `eglot` setup all of its hooks into `eldoc`, but then turn off the `eldoc` minor mode which attempts to obtain and show docs on every user command (well, there's a list of commands... but basically every keystroke)

```
(add-hook
 'eglot-managed-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   ;; we want eglot to setup callbacks from eldoc, but we don't want eldoc
   ;; running after every command. As a workaround, we disable it after we just
   ;; enabled it. Now calling `M-x eldoc` will put the help we want in the eldoc
   ;; buffer. Alternatively we could tell eglot to stay out of eldoc, and add
   ;; the hooks manually, but that seems fragile to updates in eglot.
   (eldoc-mode -1)))
```

Now you can call `M-x eldoc` to get the info at point in a buffer that pops up.

You may want to only have it show the short form in the echo area, which is a little more involved. To do that you need to upgrade to the latest version of eldoc, and modify your `eldoc-display-functions`. I personally use this little helper

```
(defun eldoc-fancy (arg)
  "`eldoc' but uses the echo area by default and a prefix will swap to a buffer."
  ;; https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot/discussions/1328
  (interactive "P")
  (let (_)
    (defvar eldoc-display-functions)
    (setq eldoc-display-functions
          (if arg '(eldoc-display-in-buffer) '(eldoc-display-in-echo-area)))
    (eldoc t)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the eldoc area moving around is distracting, especially on a small screen.  However, I think eldoc is useful, so a compromise is to keep eldoc enabled by request that it should only display a single line of information and therefore never resize the echo area:

```
(setq eldoc-echo-area-use-multiline-p nil)
```