# getting full documentation on point with eldoc and tide

Tags: echo-area, eldoc

When I have my pointer over a typescript method I get the signature of the method at the bottom of my screen. I assume this is done by tide and eldoc, but I could be wrong.

I like getting the signature, but I would also like to get the documentation of the method.
If I run `M-x tide-documentation-at-point` it picks up the full documentation, but it looks like the echo bar(?) is just showing the first line.

is this possible to fix so that I always get the full documentation?

[image: doc]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this

***Full documentation in `tide-mode` (uses `eldoc-box` for display)***`

[image: Full documentation in tide-mode (uses `eldoc-box for display)]

instead of this

***Short documentation in `tide-mode` (uses`eldoc-box for display)***

[image: Short documentation in tide-mode (uses`eldoc-box for display)]

use this

```lisp
(defun tide-eldoc-function ()
  (unless (member last-command '(next-error previous-error))
    (if (tide-method-call-p)
        (tide-command:signatureHelp #'tide-eldoc-maybe-show)
      (when (looking-at "\\s_\\|\\sw")
        (tide-command:quickinfo
         (tide-on-response-success-callback response (:ignore-empty t)
           (tide-eldoc-maybe-show
        (tide-construct-documentation (plist-get response :body))))))))
  nil)
```

instead of this

```lisp
(defun tide-eldoc-function ()
  (unless (member last-command '(next-error previous-error))
    (if (tide-method-call-p)
        (tide-command:signatureHelp #'tide-eldoc-maybe-show)
      (when (looking-at "\\s_\\|\\sw")
        (tide-command:quickinfo
         (tide-on-response-success-callback response (:ignore-empty t)
           (tide-eldoc-maybe-show (tide-doc-text (plist-get response :body))))))))
  nil)
```

That is ... `tide-eldoc-maybe-show` should receive`tide-construct-documentation`  (and not `tide-doc-text`)

---

Irrespective of HOW you display the documentatio--[Demo of `eldoc-box`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73984/31220)--the suggestion here will work.  If `minibuffer` is not showing full information--it is there, trust me---then you may have to resize the minibuffer yourself.